# Fetch API, Chrome Extension, Content Script, CORS Permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

Don't know if anyone else has noticed this.

Make an XMLHttpRequest in a content script to an image file:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
    }
};
xhttp.open("HEAD", "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png", true);
xhttp.send();
```

You get the following back:

> date: Tue, 27 Nov 2018 15:42:53 GMT x-content-type-options: nosniff
>   last-modified: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 03:17:22 GMT server: sffe age: 1136854
>   vary: Origin content-type: image/png status: 200 cache-control:
>   public, max-age=31536000 accept-ranges: bytes alt-svc: quic=":443";
>   ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35" content-length: 48061 x-xss-protection: 1;
>   mode=block expires: Wed, 27 Nov 2019 15:42:53 GMT

Make a fetch request in a content script to the same image:

```
fetch("https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png", {method: "HEAD"})
    .then(res => { 
        var headers = res.headers;
        headers.forEach(function(value, name) { console.log(`${name} : ${value}`);
     });
```

You get the following back:

> cache-control: public, max-age=31536000 content-type: image/png
>   expires: Tue, 10 Dec 2019 20:12:24 GMT last-modified: Thu, 21 Apr 2016
>   03:17:22 GMT

This is due to the W3 specs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology), which confirms to me that fetch does not totally benefit from the cross-origin manifest exemptions for Chrome Extensions. However, if you make a get request with Fetch, it succeeds.

Does anyone know if this is intentional?

Comment: Most likely yes. You should do it in the background script anyway since that'll be the only way in the future [V3 extensions API](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nPu6Wy4LWR66EFLeYInl3NzzhHzc-qnk4w4PX-0XMw8/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, very interesting. What do you think about the changes?

Comment: Not much to add to the comments in the related crbug. Hopefully we'll be able to influence the design once they start to really implement it. BTW https://crbug.com/914224 seems about to undo what I was saying above.